# Pmf and cdf of $X(\omega)=(\omega-1)^2$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

The problem is: Let be $(\Omega,F,P)$ a probability space, where $\Omega=[0,2]$ $F=Power Set(\Omega)$ and $P(.): F \rightarrow [0,1]$.

$P(\{ \omega \})= \frac{1}{10} \ \text{if}  \ \omega=0 , \frac{1}{2},2  \\ \frac{4}{10} \ \text{if}  \ \omega=1 \\ \frac{3}{10} \ \text{if}  \ \omega = \frac{3}{2}$

The random variable is $X(\omega)=(\omega-1)^2$

What is the cdf and pmf?

I try:

$P(\{ \omega \in \Omega : X(\omega)=(\omega-1)^2 \leq x \})=
P(\{ \omega \in \Omega : \omega  \leq  \sqrt{x}+1 \})
$

If $x<0$ we have $F_{X}(x)=0$

And now I don´t know how to use the hypothesis of $P(\{\omega \})$, I know that $X(\omega): \Omega \rightarrow R$.

Answer (score 3):

The PMF of $X$ is straightforward to compute, since $X$ can only take $3$ values: $0$, $1/4$, and $1$. For example, $P(X(\omega) = 1/4) = P(\omega \in \{1/2, 3/2\}) = \frac{1}{10} + \frac{3}{10} = \frac{2}{5}$. Once you have the PMF of $X$ you can compute the CDF, which should be a piecewise constant function.